# js get filename of file containing class definition

Tags: javascript, filenames

I would need to get the filename of an imported class:

fileA.js

```
export default class User {
}
```

fileB.js

```
import User from './fileA'

function getClassFilename(constructor) {
    // do something like __filename, but to get the filename where User is defined rather than the current filename
}

console.log(getClassFilename(User.constructor)) // fileA.js
```

This is the general idea. However the actual use case is based on decorators:

fileA.js

```
import someDecorator from './decorator'

@someDecorator
class User {
}
```

decorator.js

```
export default function (target) {
    // can I somehow get the target filename without passing it as a property?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That information isn't available to you by default, the module in question would have to provide a means of accessing the information.

You've mentioned `__filename` so I'm assuming you're using Node. The module providing `User` could provide that information like this:

```
export const SourceFilename = __filename;
```

Note taht there's no in-spec way to do that without Node's `__filename` (but there's one [under consideration](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-meta) and reasonably far down the path toward being added).

---

Updated answer for updated question: There's nothing stored on the class (constructor) `User` that provides this information. So again, the code defining `User` would need to provide that information (as a property on `User`, as something you can get from the module and pass separately to the decorator, etc.). Otherwise, it simply isn't available to you.

Comment: Thank your for the suggestion. Unfortunately I now had to realize that I tried to generalize my use case too much, since I am trying to get the filename within a decorator that is applied to the class. I will update the question. Sorry for that

Comment: @Chris: Basically the same answer (I've updated): Unless the module makes the information available, you won't have it to work with.

Comment: Great hint. I can just add the filename to the class as a property that I can then access without having to explicitly ex/import it.